# Connecting to a TCP/IP server via php script

Tags: php, tcp

I need to implement a php script on my website that would do the following:

1. Connect to a remote server
2. Send packet to the server
3. Receive packet from the server

Everything is already configurated on the server side to respond to packet requests, I only need to figure out how to use php to connect to TCP/IP server.

Any ideas in which direction to look?

Comment: socket programming is what u looking for...?

Comment: you mean similar to giving "ping" command in terminal,want to implement by PHP ?

Comment: PHP manual is right direction to start. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Easily with php sockets:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "Your message");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

To read more, go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: Tried it and it works in a way - I see that there is a new connection in server log. However, the page says that there has been a timeout. Do you have any idea why it might be so?

Comment: @John Maybe your server is not closing the connection, so `feof` doesn't return true?

Comment: Sorry for the bump but I'm getting a `Connection Refused (61)`, even after opening the ports via `ufw` on the server end.

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.53';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

[this is just an example from net for further look documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php)

connecting to tcp server

```
 $host="192.168.1.99"; 
    $port = 1234; // open a client connection 
    $fp = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr); 
    if (!$fp) { 
    $result = "Error: could not open socket connection"; 
    } 
    else { // get the welcome message fgets ($fp, 1024); // write the user string to the socket 
    fputs($fp, $message); // get the result $result .= fgets ($fp, 1024); // close the connection
    fputs ($fp, "END");
    fclose ($fp); // trim the result and remove the starting ?
    $result = trim($result);
    $result = substr($result, 2); // now print it to the browser 
    } ?> 
    Server said: <? echo $result; ?>
```

Comment: This is example how to create tcp server, not how to connect to one...