# Monitoring multiple machines - what kind od approach to use?

Tags: c#, php, webserver, monitoring, tcp

I writing application that runs on client PC/tablets and each few seconds is sending some kind of data (numerical...) to server over TCP/IP. This "server" should be able to manage multiple connections in the same time and show those data on screen in "real time". My idea is to write web-type application as somekind of dashboard that will create frame for each connected machine and display some data, something like this: [image]

I'm doing this for the first time and I don't have so much experience with this kind of project I'm wondering from where to start? What is the best approach to achieve this? What kind of library, technology you suggest to use?

Comment: If you're new to web servers, I think python might be able to do some of the basics here with the socket module. As for wanting the machine to be displayed, are you wanting a screenshot or just the data received?

Comment: I just want to display received numerical data. The best example is something like this: [link](https://d2n4wb9orp1vta.cloudfront.net/cms/0716_MMS_Carolina_C_IMG_0552_web.jpg;width=560;quality=90)

Comment: If you take a look at [this link about socket](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html) which should allow you to target the ip of the server, as for displaying the content you could just create a simple http server for localhost, then using a custom stylesheet

Comment: This seems acceptable but than I must choose right framework to combine python and html... Seems that is not so easy as PHP and HTML

Comment: My bad would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14081124/6004159) be of any use?

Comment: This migth be useful. I'm more familiar with PHP than Python. The thing is that there is no any complete example how how to achieve this just to see how it works.. but anyway thanks!